# detect the closest to the user point

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, coordinates, mapquest

I'm making an AIR app with Adobe Flash Pro in AS3.

I've put multiple POI point with their coordinates like that : (I'm using MapQuest)

```
var myIcon2:MapIcon = new MapIcon();

                myIcon2.setImage(new pizzaImg(),22,32);
              embeddedIconPoi = new Poi(new LatLng(-50.231838, 194.023561));
              embeddedIconPoi.rolloverAndInfoTitleText = "Pizza";
              embeddedIconPoi.icon = myIcon2;

             PoiColl.add(embeddedIconPoi);
```

I've put a geolocation function in order to place a point wherever the user is :

```
if (Geolocation.isSupported){
my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
} 
function onGeoUpdate(e:GeolocationEvent):void{
    embeddedIconPoi.latLng = new LatLng(e.latitude, e.longitude);
}
```

Now, is there a way to create a function that show the closest point to the user when he clicks on a button ?

Something like :

```
buttonClosest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goClosest, false, 0, true);

function goClosest(event:MouseEvent):void{
// Don't know what should I put here....
}
```

Thank you for your answers,

Steph

Answer (score 0):

The haversine formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) can be used to determine the distance between two points defined by latitude and longitude. Implemented in Actionscript 3.0, it would look something like this snippet of code I obtained from http://snipplr.com/view/58443/

```
private const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_MILES:int = 3963;
private const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_FEET:int =20925525;
private const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM:int =6378;
private const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_M:int =6378000;

private function distanceBetweenCoordinates(lat1:Number,lon1:Number,
                                        lat2:Number,lon2:Number,
                                        units:String="miles"):Number{

var R:int = RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_MILES;
if (units == "km"){
    R = RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM;
}
if (units == "meters"){
    R = RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_M;
}
if (units =="feet"){
    R= RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_FEET;
}

var dLat:Number = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI/180;
var dLon:Number = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI/180;

var lat1inRadians:Number = lat1 * Math.PI/180;
var lat2inRadians:Number = lat2 * Math.PI/180;

var a:Number = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                   Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * 
                   Math.cos(lat1inRadians) * Math.cos(lat2inRadians);
var c:Number = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d:Number = R * c;

return d;
}
```

Once you have that, you could simply iterate through the points you have and find the distance between each and the user's point and then get the minimum.

That would probably look something like this (I'm not familiar with the MapQuests API for AS3, but you should be able to adapt this code properly)

```
function goClosest(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var minDistance:Number = int.MAX_VALUE;
    var poiWithSmallestDistanceFromUser:Poi = null;
    for each(var poi:POI in pois)
    {
        var distance:Number = distanceBetweenCoordinates(poi.lat, poi.lon, userPoi.lat, userPoi.lon);
        if (distance < minDistance)
        {
            minDistance = distance;
            poiWithSmallestDistanceFromUser = poi;
        }
    }

}
```

After the for loop executes you're left with minDistance and poiWithSmallestDistanceFromUser.

Hope this helps!